# Using .len() in IF THEN statement in ArcMap field calculator

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, arcmap, field-calculator, string

I have a string field with values of varying lengths (1-4).  I need each value to have a length of 5 characters by adding zeros to the value until the length equals 5.  For example:

```
123
```

needs to be:

```
00123
```

I am writing a Python function in ArcMap's Field Calculator but it is incorrect.  This is my code:

```
def zeros(photoLen):
  if photoLen == 4:
    return "0"
  elif photoLen == 3:
    return "00"
  elif photoLen == 2:
    return "000"
  elif photoLen == 1:
    return "0000"
  else:
    return 0
```

And then I call the function like this:

```
zeros(!photoStr!)
```

What do I need to change so this function will work?

Comment: You're passing a string so if len(photoLen)==4: is more correct, if photoLen == 4: will give a 'type mismatch' error comparing a string with a number and then return "0" + photoLen... but still, the answer by DWyne is how to right justify with a set number of 0's.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In addition to @DWynne's answer, I'll add that there is a built-in python function that does exactly this (located a little bit further down the page on DWynne's link).  It's called [zfill](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.zfill) and according to the documentation:

> Returns the numeric string left filled with zeros in a string of
>   length width. A sign prefix is handled correctly. The original string
>   is returned if width is less than or equal to len(s).

So, you can use this in your expression:

```
!photoStr!.zfill(5)
```

It's no better than using rjust, but it's a bit shorter. I use it all the time when I want to pad a string with zeroes.

Comment: I like this better than my answer

Comment: If there was an integer field called `photo`, just use `str(!photo!).zfill(5)`

Answer (score 8):

Actually, you could do this without a function. Try using [str.rjust](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.rjust). An expression of `!photoStr!.rjust(5, '0')` will return a string with padded 0's to the left of your number string.

- '1' becomes '00001'
- '12' becomes '00012'
- '123' becomes '00123'
- '1234' becomes '01234'

Answer (score 2):

Python's [builtin string formatting](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html) will do what you want:

```
'{0:0>5d}'.format(photoStr)
```

The 0 before the : means first argument (photoStr), the next 0 is the fill character, > means right-aligned, 5 is the length of the formatted string, then d means a decimal number.

For example:

```
>>> '{0:0>5d}'.format(123)
'00123'
>>> '{0:0>5d}'.format(13)
'00013'
>>> '{0:0>5d}'.format(1)
'00001'
```

Answer (score 1):

These are great string functions that I didn't know about.  Just for good measure, I'll add a method I've used in the past:

expression:

```
zeros(!photoStr!)
```

code block:

```
def zeros(value):
    desired_len  = 5
    return (desired_len-len(value))*"0"+value
```

Comment: You could add the `desired_len` as a parameter to the function.  Like `def zeros(value, desired_len):`.  That way, you can change the length as required. Then, you call it like `zeros(!photoStr!, 5)` or `zeros(!photoStr!, 8)` etc.